# Messages.fetch and bulkDelete don't delete messages discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Here is my code, everything up to clearChat functon works. It throws no error but it doesn't delete the messages.

```
    const bot = new Discord.Client();
    bot.on('message', msg => {
      
       const args = msg.content.substring(config.prefix.length).split(' ');

       switch (args[0]) {
           case 'clear':

               if(isNaN(args[1])) return msg.reply('Define the amount of messages you want to clear!');
               else if(args[1] > 101 ) return msg.reply('Cannot clear more than 100 messages!');
               else if(args[1] < 1)) return msg.reply('Must clear at least 1 message!');
               else {

                    clearChat = async(msg, args) => {

                         let deleteAmount = +args[1] + 1;

                         messages = await msg.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: deleteAmount }).then(async(messages) => {
                             await msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
                         });
                    };
               };
               break;
       };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because you never actually execute the delete part of your code.

You need to define it as a function to run it the way you want to here.

```
async function clearChat (msg, args) {
            
    let deleteAmount = +args[1] + 1;

    messages = await msg.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: deleteAmount }).then(async (messages) => {
        await msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
    });
}
```

Once defined correctly you need to call that function

```
else {
    clearChat(msg, args)
}
```

In addition to that, you have an extra `)` in your `else if (args[1] < 1)`.

The complete code should look a little something like this:

```
if (isNaN(args[1])) return msg.reply('Define the amount of messages you want to clear!');
else if (args[1] > 101) return msg.reply('Cannot clear more than 100 messages!');
else if (args[1] < 1) return msg.reply('Must clear at least 1 message!');
else {
    clearChat(msg, args)
}
        
async function clearChat (msg, args) {
            
    let deleteAmount = +args[1] + 1;

    messages = await msg.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: deleteAmount }).then(async (messages) => {
        await msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
    });
}
```

Comment: another the problem is that  `msg.channel.messages.fetch` is not recognized as a function but `msg.channel.fetchMessages` works.

Comment: when I tried your solution the only things I had to change were the ones described above. What version of discord.js are you using?